# Can I set the dimensions of a screen capture in QuickTime Player 10

Tags: macos, screenshot, quicktime

I'm using QuickTime Player 10 on a Mac to create a Screen Recording. Is it possible to set the dimensions of the movie or the location that needs to be captured? I have to create multiple movies using precise screen dimensions and locations.

Comment: I record the entire screen, or a much larger area than needed, and trim it afterwards with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can record the specific part you want directly with `ffmpeg` see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768069/2836621

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a way, except an iterative workaround.

1. Window -> Show Movie Inspector (⌘I)
2. File -> New Screen Recording
3. Select a rectangle and record one second
4. Inspect size (and throw away the recording)
5. Repeat back to 2, adjust the rectangle until the size is right

It would be much easier if the developers of the Quicktime app would change the rectangular select to behave like the Screenshot app and show the size in a small popup box while you are adjusting the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I came with the same question -- it looks like no. However, one could try [Monosnap](https://monosnap.com/) which does give more details on the selected area (pixel height and width) and is free on OS X and Windows. So far in usage, it seems good.

Comment: @PlateReverb Confusing but looks like still has a free tier on the pricing page. Non-free appears to have other options like storing artifacts on their servers? Not sure. I'm no longer using it so definitely something to watch for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inspect element and then the ruler to set the size of a window which you can then match to Quicktime.

See this image

[image]

In this case i've set it at 1400px width by 700px height which can then be reduced to 700 x 350 to insert the embed form HTML for the video into webpages using the best aspect ratio.