# FFmpeg 3.3.4 avfoundation to record only a specific section of the screen on macOS Sierra using the command line

Tags: macos, shell, ffmpeg, video-recording

I'm using FFmpeg version 3.3.4 (installed via brew) through the command line to record my desktop during some automated tests on my macOS Sierra (10.12.6).

I would like to record only a specific section of the screen but, unfortunately, I'm not able to find the proper options in the documentation to reach my goal.

According to the [FFmpeg documentation for avfoundation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#avfoundation), this is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg 
-f avfoundation    // avfoundation
-pix_fmt uyvy422   // pixel format
-i 1               // input: desktop
-r 30              // framerate for output
[PATH]/test.mp4      // filename
```

When I run this command I have the following output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --enable-openssl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.0/include/openjpeg-2.3 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[avfoundation @ 0x7fb7d4005800] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, avfoundation, from '1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 7263.782833, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 1920x1080, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7d4028400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7d4028400] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7d4028400] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '[PATH]/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv422p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   83 fps= 28 q=-1.0 Lsize=     525kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1612.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.889x
```

I tried to use the `-video_size` option to set the video frame size, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to find the name of the **AVFoundation** device that corresponds to your screen:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] [0] HD Pro Webcam C920
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] [1] FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] [2] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] [0] HD Pro Webcam C920
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc1cd40ec60] [1] Built-in Microphone
```

So my screen is device `[2]` because I have two cameras attached and they are devices `[0]` and `[1]`.

Then, as you are on a Mac, you will probably want to use **QuickTime** to view videos, so you need to ensure you make videos that are compatible - that means using `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "2:0" -vf  "crop=1024:768:400:800" -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -r 10 out.mov
```

The 1024x768 are the width and height of the video, and the 400:800 are the offset from top-left of screen that I want to record from.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work fine. I have two more questions:
1) what does the `-y` options do?
2) adding the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` after the `-i` and `-vf` options I have the following alert `[avfoundation @ 0x7f8d41003400] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.`  with the list of supported format. what lib/extension should I add?

Comment: The `-y` means *"yes, it's ok"*  for `ffmpeg` to overwrite previous files of the same name - which often happens when testing stuff again and again.

Comment: You should add the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` **after** all the input stuff so `ffmpeg` knows you want the output to be in `yuv420` so that QuickTime can play it. If you put it near the start of the line, `ffmpeg` assumes you want to make the input from the screen come in in that format - which it can't provide.

Comment: thank you for your answers. According to your solution, this is my new command `fmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -vf  "crop=1020:1080:0:0" -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -r 30 test.mp4` that raises the above mentioned exception. Nevertheless, QuickTime is able to open the mp4 file.