# List available cameras OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7

I have multiple webcams connected to my PC and I would like to select one camera based on its info (name, resolution etc.). Is there a way to list all the cameras available on a PC, instead of trying all the indices in cv2.VideoCapture()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197825/c-opencv-2-4-11-list-all-cameras

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is negative. OpenCV doesn't have a method for listing the available video capture devices on your system. If you look at the code you see how currently OpenCV handles invalid device indices that don't exist. For instance for MacOS here is [the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_avfoundation_mac.mm#L362):

```
if ( cameraNum < 0 || devices.count <= NSUInteger(cameraNum) ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "OpenCV: out device of bound (0-%ld): %d\n", devices.count-1, cameraNum);
    [localpool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

You see `devices.count` returns the number of available devices but OpenCV doesn't have a method to return that to the user.

The relevant code for Windows is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b39cd06249213220e802bb64260727711d9fc98c/modules/videoio/src/cap_winrt_video.cpp#L100):

```
if ((unsigned)m_deviceID >= m_devices.Get()->Size)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("Video::initGrabber - no video device found\n");
    return false;
}
```

Again there is no function for returning `m_devices.Get()->Size` to the user. The Linux code is a bit more complex.

If you're building OpenCV from code you could add a function that returns the number of available devices. Or even better submit a pull request to OpenCV with your patch.

Comment: Mmmm... I wonder if AVFoundation enumerates the devices for OpenCV in the same order as for `ffmpeg` https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768069/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell it should be the same order with one difference. ffmpeg list both video and muxed devices: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavdevice/avfoundation.m#L703-L704
opencv is enumerating only the video devices. But both use the same method of AVCaptureDevice so the order of video devices must be the same.

Answer (score 29):

To answer the title of your question, you can use a while loop:

```
import cv2


def list_ports():
    """
    Test the ports and returns a tuple with the available ports 
    and the ones that are working.
    """
    is_working = True
    dev_port = 0
    working_ports = []
    available_ports = []
    while is_working:
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(dev_port)
        if not camera.isOpened():
            is_working = False
            print("Port %s is not working." %dev_port)
        else:
            is_reading, img = camera.read()
            w = camera.get(3)
            h = camera.get(4)
            if is_reading:
                print("Port %s is working and reads images (%s x %s)" %(dev_port,h,w))
                working_ports.append(dev_port)
            else:
                print("Port %s for camera ( %s x %s) is present but does not reads." %(dev_port,h,w))
                available_ports.append(dev_port)
        dev_port +=1
    return available_ports,working_ports
```

It's quite easy solution to implement on your code.

### Version 2

As @ketza noticed, there might be cases in which the working ports are not sequential, this version will test at least 5 non working ports before exiting the while loop:

```
import cv2
    
    
def list_ports():
    """
    Test the ports and returns a tuple with the available ports and the ones that are working.
    """
    non_working_ports = []
    dev_port = 0
    working_ports = []
    available_ports = []
    while len(non_working_ports) < 6: # if there are more than 5 non working ports stop the testing. 
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(dev_port)
        if not camera.isOpened():
            non_working_ports.append(dev_port)
            print("Port %s is not working." %dev_port)
        else:
            is_reading, img = camera.read()
            w = camera.get(3)
            h = camera.get(4)
            if is_reading:
                print("Port %s is working and reads images (%s x %s)" %(dev_port,h,w))
                working_ports.append(dev_port)
            else:
                print("Port %s for camera ( %s x %s) is present but does not reads." %(dev_port,h,w))
                available_ports.append(dev_port)
        dev_port +=1
    return available_ports,working_ports,non_working_ports
```

Comment: I found this more useful than the selected answer because it is in Python.  Thank you

Comment: I actually had a case where there were cameras available at port 0 and port 2, but none at port 1. The while loop in the answer would exit after finding port 1 does not work. I just exchanged the while loop with a for loop to some arbitrary max port number (10) to see it all.

Comment: @ketza thanks for your feedback I have updated the answer.

Comment: FYI The width and height reported are what the camera is configured to output in opencv, not the actual full resolution of the camera.

Answer (score 4):

first install package :
`pip install pygrabber==0.1`

code #

```
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph

graph = FilterGraph()

print(graph.get_input_devices())# list of camera device 

try:
    device =graph.get_input_devices().index("name camera that I want to use it ")

except ValueError as e:

    device = graph.get_input_devices().index("Integrated Webcam")#use default camera if the name of the camera that I want to use is not in my list

vid=cv2.VideoCapture(device)
```

Comment: In case it is not obvious, pygrabber is Windows only.