# VideoCapture shows "no camera access" placeholder image

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am trying to display a live video feed from camera. When I run the program, ret returns true but cv2.imshow() displays a placeholder image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
#initialize video from the webcam
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened()) # ->returns True

while True:
# ret tells if the camera works properly. Frame is an actual frame from the video feed
    ret, frame= video.read()
    if ret ==True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Detect the faces
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
        # Draw the rectangle around each face
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        # Display
        cv2.imshow('img', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff==27:
            break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

cv2.imshow('img', frame) opens the following window.

[image]

So, I checked whether the Camera permission is allowed and it seems it already is. I am using MacOS Big Sur (version 11.6).

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with your Mac Model and macOS version

Comment: Is there some hardware "closer" for the camera (like in new Thinkpad notebooks)? Do you have to give your application permissions to access the camera? Is it sufficient to give permissions to the terminal instead of the actual application?

Comment: @Micka I ran the code on VScode and terminal. As you can see in the pic above, both have the Camera permission.

Comment: @Luke I updated my question with my Mac info. I am using MacOS BigSur(version 11.6).

Comment: Are you using an M1 Mac?

Comment: @Luke No. Mine is Mac pro released in 2019 so its processor is Intel. I updated my Mac from Catalina to BigSur.

Comment: Can you post the output of `cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened()` in your question?

Comment: @Luke I updated the code with the output. It returns True

Comment: are you able to access the camera from different apps? I dont know macOS, does the crossed-camera-icon have a standard meaning (like "no permissions", or "camera locked")?

Comment: What camera is it and how is it attached? Can you read the camera directly with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: e.g. if I use the hardware-lock / camera-cover (ThinkShutter) of my Thinkpad I'll get this kind of image from the driver: https://i.postimg.cc/pr5JJpd6/camera-cover.jpg

Comment: I changed CameraID from 0 to 1 and the video feed is displayed correctly now. I am not sure why 0 does not display the video feed even if cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened() returns true. Anyway,  thanks to all for helping me solve the problem.

Comment: you *may* need permissions on the python runtime/interpreter, not vscode or terminal.

Comment: do you have any "virtual webcam" software installed? any streaming programs that have this icon?

Comment: If you read here, you can see how to check the device numbers on macOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768069/2836621

Comment: Thanks to all your help, I realized CameraID 0 was used by different app(webcam software) installed long ago.