# MacOS - how to choose audio device from terminal

Tags: python, macos, audio, ffmpeg

I've been working on a Python program to create audio and also play back existing sound files. I can spawn multiple processes and have them all play to the laptop speakers, but I was wondering if it was possible to send each signal to a separate sound device. This is so I can apply effects to some processes but not all together.

I'm using a MacBook and python `simpleaudio`, which calls AudioToolbox to connect to the output device. I've also got `ffmpeg` installed, so could use `ffplay` if that is easier. The `pydub` library uses this - it exports the current wave to a temp file then uses subprocess and `ffplay` to play it back.

I can get a list of devices, but am not sure how to use this list to choose a device.

```
% ffplay -devices
Devices:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
  E audiotoolbox    AudioToolbox output device
 D  avfoundation    AVFoundation input device
 D  lavfi           Libavfilter virtual input device
  E sdl,sdl2        SDL2 output device
 D  x11grab         X11 screen capture, using XCB
```

I did see a post that suggested using `ffmpeg` to list devices, again I can't figure out how to use this list.

```
% ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=r=44100 -f audiotoolbox -list_devices true -
Input #0, lavfi, from 'sine=r=44100':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AudioToolbox @ 0x135e3f230] CoreAudio devices:
[AudioToolbox @ 0x135e3f230] [0]               Background Music, (null)
[AudioToolbox @ 0x135e3f230] [1]   Background Music (UI Sounds), BGMDevice_UISounds
[AudioToolbox @ 0x135e3f230] [2]         MacBook Air Microphone, BuiltInMicrophoneDevice
[AudioToolbox @ 0x135e3f230] [3]           MacBook Air Speakers, BuiltInSpeakerDevice
[AudioToolbox @ 0x135e3f230] [4]               Aggregate Device, ~:AMS2_Aggregate:0
Output #0, audiotoolbox, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 pcm_s16le
size=N/A time=00:00:05.06 bitrate=N/A speed=0.984x    
video:0kB audio:436kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

This does at least give me a recognisable list of devices. If I add more Aggregate Devices, can I play back different files to each device?

Comment: I don't do audio, only images, but my answer here shows how to list macOS devices then choose one for the next `ffmpeg` command and I guess it's similar for audio https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768069/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nobody knows how to do this with `simpleaudio` or `ffmpeg`, but the `sounddevice` library has much better control of I/O devices. Another dependency, yay!

https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/